# How to open different browsers with expo?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I want to build a helper app which would automatize some tasks that are currently done manually. It’s not very complicated: the app receives a link from a server and it should be able to open it in a specific browser from a list of browsers which are already installed on the phone both on Android and iOS. I’m using Expo with Linking and URI schemes.

I’ve managed to do it on iOS on the browsers which interest me like this:

```
open Firefox with Linking.openURL('firefox://open-url?url='+ url);
open Chrome with Linking.openURL('googlechrome://' + url);
open Safari with Linking.openURL(url);
```

The problem is on Android. I’ve only managed to launch Chrome with:
`Linking.openURL('googlechrome://navigate?url=' + url);`
I still want to open Firefox and UC Browser but I can’t even launch the apps with their URI scheme nevermind passing the url. Tried:

`Linking.openURL('firefox://);`
`Linking.openURL('ucbrowser://);`

I'm thinking maybe I need to trigger a Intent for these browsers and I tried with `IntentLauncherAndroid.startActivityAsync("android.intent.action.VIEW", intentParams);`
 but I can't figure out what Intent params I need to open a specific app with params (Firefox/Uc Browser with a custom url in this case).